# How can I dynamically select and expand a certain search node depending on its score and the score of its children?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'm familiar with most path finding and graph search algorithms, but I'm not sure how I can solve this dynamically and I'm sure I've overlooked something .

Currently, my approach is very static and hard-coded. This is about a single player tetris like game for which I create the AI.

The current and next piece are known, no further. Since the branching factor is pretty wide, I only look at the best 3 states of all possible states for the current piece and then again the best 3 states that are generated with the next piece.

To get a deeper look at the future at depth 3 I generate all states for all possible pieces, get the best and calculate the average for them. This could be continued for further depths and only depend on CPU power.

Since I only take the best 3, then the next best 3 and then only the best to calculate the average, this doesn't seem balanced. I would need something that dynamically selects and expands a certain search node depending on its score and the score of its children..

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can I dynamically select and expand a certain search node depending on its score and the score of its children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do have a more informed search strategy, you can look at

- [Expecti-Max algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectiminimax_tree), which is a version of Alpha-Beta search for stochastic problems, or
- [Monte-Carlo Tree Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search) (or UCT in particular).